# How to initialize entities fields representing their datetime of insertion into database using JPA?

Tags: java, jpa, database-design

My JPA Entity has one field like this:

```
@Column(nullable = false)
private LocalDateTime entryDateTime;
```

I want *entryDateTime* to be calculated when the entry is successfully inserted into database.

I think of two ways to do it:

- Using `@PostPersist` method, in which case i need to remove `@Column(nullable = false)`
- Using `@PrePersist` method, in which case `@Column(nullable = false)` can be there, but what if inserting somehow fails? I do not want my object to have *entryDateTime* initialized then, so i would need to set it back to null.

Designing entities might by affected by opinions, but i think the question is not opinion-based. I am looking for most efficient way, in which i would not need to remove `@Column(nullable = false)`. Is there a way how to do it or a better approach? Or should i stick with one of those ways i described?

Comment: Well, when insertion fails you'd normally get an exception at the end of the transaction and the data would not make it to the database. Since you shouldn't keep entities around for too long (in most cases at most until the end of the transaction) this shouldn't be a problem. In case of a failed insert you just don't get anything. - There's one thing to note though: setting value in your entity would mean the time represented is the time of object creation and not when the persist actually happened. If that's an issue you might want to use DB default values.

Comment: Another thought on `@PostPersist`: this would require an update to the database to persist  `entryDateTime` so you'd put more load onto your system and the update might fail as well so you'd have to deal with that. That bveing said I'd consider `@PrePersist` the more viable option.

Comment: If you really want to the timestamp from the database you should add the DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP to the database table. And not do it with JPA.

Answer (score 0):

Which implementation of the jpa are you using?

In Hibernate you could annotate your Field with

```java
@CreationTimestamp
```

[Hibernate Doc](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/current/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#mapping-generated-CreationTimestamp)

and in Spring you could annotate it with

```java
@CreatedDate
```

[Spring Doc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#auditing.annotations)

Comment: I am using OpenJPA. I am not aware of there being this option.

Answer (score 0):

Create a method in your entity class annotated with PrePersist

for example:

```java
public class UserEntity {
    private Date createdAt;

    ...

    @PrePersist
    public void prePersist() {
        createdAt = new Date();
    }
}
```

That should work